# How to properly pass paramethers to $resource(...).save in angular

Tags: php, angularjs, session-variables

I am developingan angularJS application, and I need to use $resources and pass to a php file a $_POSY value, then I will set the value to $_SESSION and  end the php script.

This is the code I wrote :

```
var setData = function(place) {
        // Angular $http() and then() both return promises themselves

        return $resource('./PHP/session/placeSession.php').
               save({ lastPlace: json }).
               $promise.then(function(res) {
                  console.log(res + "   " + json);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
               });
    };
```

and this is the placeSession.php

```
<?php

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['lastPlace'] = $_POST['lastPlace'];
?>
```

Is it right ? the value in lastPlace is :[object Object]   if I display it in the console .

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The answer is if the code I wrote is right, because I am getting no errors